# Tagging does not work with the Subversion plugin

Tags: hudson, continuous-integration, jenkins

I am using Jenkins 1.417 with the Subversion plugin. When I am trying to tag a build nothing happens. No message, no error, no tags created.

So, my question is - **how to tag builds in Jenkins when the version control is Subversion**?

**Additional information:**

When I am trying to tag a build without giving the credentials, the operation fails:

```
Tagging svn://dev-profiler/common/trunk (rev.65) to svn://dev-profiler/common/tags/Test-1
ERROR: Failed to tag
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: No credential to try. Authentication failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:37)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:32)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:219)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.sasl.SVNSaslAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SVNSaslAuthenticator.java:304)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.sasl.SVNSaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SVNSaslAuthenticator.java:91)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNConnection.authenticate(SVNConnection.java:173)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.authenticate(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1265)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.getCommitEditorInternal(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1572)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getCommitEditor(SVNRepository.java:2467)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.copyReposToRepos(SVNCopyDriver.java:368)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.setupCopy(SVNCopyDriver.java:628)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCopyClient.doCopy(SVNCopyClient.java:426)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionTagAction$TagWorkerThread.perform(SubversionTagAction.java:262)
    at hudson.model.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:126)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: No credential to try. Authentication failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:146)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:89)
    ... 14 more
Completed
```

Which is good, because it is supposed to fail when no credentials are given. So the negative path is working as expected.

**P.S.**

Exactly the same problem is described [here](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Tag-this-build-not-working-subversion-td384218.html) and on the [jenkins issues site](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9961) and on the [respective google group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jenkinsci-users/4UVKFxXA9Jo/overview). All to no avail.

**P.P.S.**

I realize that without logs little can be done, but one has to know the names of the loggers in order to activate them and thus generate the logs, which I do not know. If someone provides me with the logger names then I would gladly post the logs.

**EDIT**

I activated hudson.scm log to level All. This is what appears there:

```
03/07/2011 10:10:08 hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl$SVNAuthenticationProviderImpl fromProvider    FINE: global.requestClientAuthentication(svn.simple,svn://dev-profiler/common,<svn://dev-profiler:3690> Temporary Shunra Repository)=>null
03/07/2011 10:10:08 hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl$RemotableSVNAuthenticationProviderImpl getCredential    FINE: getCredential(<svn://dev-profiler:3690> Temporary Shunra Repository)=>null
03/07/2011 10:10:08 hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl$SVNAuthenticationProviderImpl fromProvider    FINE: local.requestClientAuthentication(svn.simple,svn://dev-profiler/common,<svn://dev-profiler:3690> Temporary Shunra Repository)=>null
```

Now, when I try to tag I see this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to tag
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: No credential to try. Authentication failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:37)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:32)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:219)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.sasl.SVNSaslAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SVNSaslAuthenticator.java:304)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.sasl.SVNSaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SVNSaslAuthenticator.java:91)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNConnection.authenticate(SVNConnection.java:173)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.authenticate(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1265)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.getCommitEditorInternal(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1572)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getCommitEditor(SVNRepository.java:2467)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.copyReposToRepos(SVNCopyDriver.java:368)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.setupCopy(SVNCopyDriver.java:628)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCopyClient.doCopy(SVNCopyClient.java:426)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionTagAction$TagWorkerThread.perform(SubversionTagAction.java:262)
    at hudson.model.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:126)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: No credential to try. Authentication failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:146)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:89)
    ... 14 more
Completed
```

This is very strange, because I do provide the credentials...

Comment: Please edit this question to actually include the question. Do not send people offsite to read somebody elses question to even find out what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Also, it seems you already asked another question related to this. Since this one does not actually include the question I can't tell for sure, but it seems like they are asking about the same problem. Please just edit the first one to combine any useful data from this one. [Using the promote builds plugin to tag subversion repository in jenkins](http://serverfault.com/questions/283313/using-the-promote-builds-plugin-to-tag-subversion-repository-in-jenkins)

Comment: I have edited the question. It is not the same question as http://serverfault.com/questions/283313/using-the-promote-builds-plugin-to-tag-subversion-repository-in-jenkins

Comment: again, please add a clear question to your post. I don't know what your asking! It should be really obvious, if you want people to help.

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you provide the credentials?

I had the same problem, due missing/wrong credentials. I followed the description in [this page](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/felipegaucho/archive/2009/03/hudson_svncance.html) where described how you can change/set credentials for SVN-repositories.